# Meaning of "vom Zeitaufwand her" in an example sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this example sentence in DWDS on [*Zeitaufwand*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zeitaufwand)

> Ich mache die Arbeit hier in der Workstation vom Zeitaufwand her hauptberuflich.

but I do not understand the meaning of "vom Zeitaufwand her".

Comment: What userunknown relates to, is that *Workstation* means a powerful PC, E.g. for CAD construction. Working *in* it is hardly possible. *Station* is also used for the departement of a clinic, but then most likely preposition would be *auf*.

Comment: @guidot: the point here is that it is a quote from the *Süddeutsche* without further context. I believe it is highly irrelevant to the question what they meant with *Workstation*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That phrase **von (Dativ) her** means *taking … into account*.

> Diese Arbeit ist **vom** Zeitaufwand **her** mein Hauptberuf.

*Taking the time spent into account, this job is my main job.*

> **Von** der Lage **her** ist das ein schönes Haus.

*Taking the location into account, this is a nice house.*

Answer (score 2):

Here are more examples for the use of "vom xzy her" in good casual German.

> Vom Preis her ist das Zimmer gut, aber die Qualität lässt zu wünschen übrig.

Price-wise the room is good, but quality could be better.

> Vom Geschmack her ist das Eis super, aber wenn man die Zutatenliste liest, kommt einem das Grausen.

As for its taste, this ice-cream is good. But reading the ingredients list you will be shocked.

> Vom alltäglichen Zusammenleben her ist es mit ihr klasse, aber wir haben grundsätzliche weltanschauliche Differenzen

Regarding everyday life living with her is phantastic, however, we have deeply rooted differences in terms of our worldview.

(Don't judge me on the English sentences. If somebody has suggestions for improvements, you are welcome.)

Note that *vom xyz her* is used rather in casual mode of language. In formal writing or a parliamentary speech it would be inappropriate. Formal alternatives are

> In Bezug auf...
>
> Bezüglich...
>
> Bezogen auf...
>
> Betrachtet man...